# Casting one class to another which interited from same baseClass

Tags: c#, inheritance

It is possible to cast class1 to class2 ?
result variable retrieves always null value.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Class1 class1 = new Class1();
        class1.Field1 = "1";
        class1.Field2 = "2";
        class1.Field3 = "3";
        class1.Field4 = "4";
        class1.Field5 = "5";
        BaseClass base1 =  (BaseClass)class1;

        Class2 class2 = base1 as Class2;

        string result = class2.Field1;
    }
}

public class BaseClass
{
    public string Field1 { get; set; }
    public string Field2 { get; set; }
    public string Field3 { get; set; }
}

public class Class1 : BaseClass
{
    public string Field4 { get; set; }
    public string Field5 { get; set; }
}

public class Class2 : BaseClass
{
    public string Field6 { get; set; }
    public string Field7 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I think he wants "Class2 class2 = base1 as Class2" to work.

Comment: For this feature, I would implement a constructor that takes an existing `BaseClass` instance and copies values from it. Casting using a custom operator would be confusing.

Answer (score 5):

No, it's not possible to cast like this. You'll need to write your own conversion method or operator. The object `base1` refers to simply *isn't* a Class2. What would its values of `Field6` and `Field7` be?

Comment: I am expecting to have new Class2 instence with Field1, Field2 and Field3 values. Field6 and Field7 can be null because they are not in base class.

Comment: Change Class1, Class2, BaseClass with real world examples, and you'll see why that does not make sense.

Comment: @Cihan: Then you'll need to create a `Class2` constructor which takes a `BaseClass` parameter and copies the values from that into the new object.

Comment: that's exactly what I said (commented) 2 minutes ago :-P. Also +1 for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to cast Class1 to Class2. But to BaseClass is, of course, possible.

Answer (score 0):

"Can it be done?"

No, they are both `BaseClass` and can both be cast to `BaseClass`, but you cannot cast `Class1` to `Class2` or vice versa. Nor can `BaseClass` be cast to `Class1`. You can only cast upwards in the inheritance chain.

If you are trying to overcome cumbersome mappings or something, consider [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) for your mappings which is really helpful in those cases.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that your `Class1` cannot be casted as `Class2`.

When you do

```
BaseClass base1 =  (BaseClass)class1;
```

You are only changing the reference and not the object itself. Object knows that it is a `Class1`. So when you try to cast as `Class2`, it fails since one is not inherited from the other.

Answer (score 0):

The problem line is:

```
Class2 class2 = base1 as Class2;
```

The problem is that this would have no idea what to do with Field6 or Field7. You have to write your own conversion so that these fields get sorted out.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the question is "Why does `string result = class2.Field1;` die with a NullReferenceException" I'll try to explain.

Lets rename the classes a bit. Lets say BaseClass is Vehicle, Class1 is Car, and Class2 is SpaceShuttle.

So,

```
BaseClass base1 =  (BaseClass)class1; 
//becomes
Vehicle myVehicle =  (Vehicle) myCar;
```

No problem there, the cast is not even neccessary. A car is always a vehicle. But

```
Class2 class2 = base1 as Class2;
//becomes
SpaceShuttle shuttle = myVehicle as SpaceShuttle.
```

Here i'm saying that my vehicle is a spaceShuttle, when in fact is an old Honda Civic. The compiler notices this, and sets the `shuttle` variable to null, because thats what the [`as` operator does](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). If you ask `myVehicle` is it a SpaceShuttle, it will respond with a *NO*, like this:

```
bool isShuttle = (myVehicle is SpaceShuttle); //false
```

So even if both SpaceShuttle and Car have the same property, inherited from Vehicles, lets say `Color` or `Owner` or whatever, it does not mean that I can treat my car as a space shuttle.